# Code Igniter controller - can't use uri->segment with function index()?

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I'm working with code igniter and for some reason, the url http://mysite.com/account/100 gives me a 404 error but http://mysite.com/account actualy works.  Here's what my controller account.php looks like.

```
   class account extends Controller {


    function account()
    {
      parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
     echo 'hello';
      echo $this->uri->segment(2);
    }
    }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It may be that it is trying to call 100 as a method instead of an argument so try account/index/100 and see if it changes.

Comment: ah you are right.   Is it possible to have the 100 not treated as a function?  For example, if function not found, then treat it as a url variable?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be, at least not without editing CodeIgniter itself.

Comment: I take that back, you can use routes to do it for instance.

$route['account/(:num)'] = "account/index/$1"


I believe that would work. See the URI Routing user guide for more info.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: great thanks, can you add that routing tip to your answer, then i'll check mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested a simple account class like you have and it is trying to call 100 as a method of account, instead your URL after index.php should be account/index/100 and it works fine.

This can be solved using routing for example.

```
$route['account/(:num)'] = "accounts/index/$1";
```

is what you are looking for. You can look over the [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) user guide
for more info.

CodeIgniter requires that your controller name be capitalized, and the filename lowercase so try changing your controller to.

```
class Account extends Controller { }
```

and your filename account.php

Comment: sorry, that was just a typing mistake in my question.  I actually ahve the bracket in my controller and it is named account.php

Answer (score 0):

Add this route and you are good

```
$route['account/(:any)'] = "account/index/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because when you request  http://example.com/account, it looks *index()* method. 
But when you request  http://example.com/account/100, is looking for *100()* method. Which is not present. 
You may tweak the code like this.

```
class account extends Controller {
 public function account()
 {
   parent::Controller();
 }

 public function index()
 {
  echo 'hello';
 }

 public function id(){
  echo $this->uri->segment(2);
 }
 public function alternative($id){
  echo $id;
 }
}
```

you'll call url like this: http://example.com/account/id/100

or you can do like this 
http://example.com/account/alternative/100